# jqGrid and typeahead with local data

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid, typeahead

Ned help on getting jqgrid to use typeahead with local data and no ajax call. taking the example from the the jgrid site (http://www.guriddo.net/demo/bootstrap/ : Search Toolbar: Search Controls (datepicker, autocomplete, dropdown, checkbox, custom, etc) where they have :

```
label : "Ship Name",
name: 'ShipName',
width: 150,
searchoptions: {
    // dataInit is the client-side event that fires upon initializing the toolbar search field for a column
    // use it to place a third party control to customize the toolbar
    dataInit: function (element) {
       $(element).attr("autocomplete","off").typeahead({ 
           appendTo : "body",
            source: function(query, proxy) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/jsonp/autocompletepbs.php?callback=?&acelem=ShipName',
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {term: query},
                    success : proxy
                });
            }
       });
    },
    sopt : ['cn']
}
```

i'm trying to use the same logic but with local data :

```
var namelist = ["name 1","name 2", bla bla bla...,"name x"]

nameGrid.jqGrid({
    url         : '/ajaxx/ajax.getList.php',
    mtype       : "POST",
    datatype    : "json",
    page        : 1,
    colNames    :   ['ID', 'program Name', 'program Group'],
    colModel    : [
                    {   name: 'ID',key: true, width: 75, search:false, hidden:false},
                    {   name: 'Name',width: 200, seacrh:true,  stype:'text',
                          cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
                              return 'style="white-space: normal;'
                         },
                        searchoptions: {
                            dataInit: function (element) {
                                $(element).attr("autocomplete","off").typeahead({
                                    appendTo : "body",
                                    source: namelist,
                                });
                            },
                            sopt : ['cn']
                        }
                    }
                ],
    //rest of options
    .........
});
```

when i start typing into the search field of the grid, it only shows only one letter and only the first letter that it matches. for example let say i have [Alain, James, Richard] as names if i start looking for Alain and i type "a" it will show all the rows with only "a"  and if i type a second letter like "l",  all will disappear and i'm back to a normal text box with my two letters "al" in it